Simulink model parameter update and observations at discrete times
I have a Simulink model M which include a parameter p.
Assume that I want to simulate M over the the time period [0, T].
Also assume that I get an output y from the model M.
Now consider discrete time points [0, $t_1$, $t_2$, ...., $t_n$] in the time interval [0, T].
At each $t_i$, I want to change p in the model and want to get the value of $y$.
How can I do this?

Are the values $p_1, p_2, \dots p_n$ known before the simulation starts? or is $p_k$ know only after simulation has reached $t_k$ and cannot be computed from signals present in the diagram?

Why not make $p$ a signal, which is driven by a source rather than a parameter? signals can change during the simulation. e.g. replace a gain block with gain parameter $p$ with a product block which takes the original signal as one input and $p(t)$ as the second input. If this is not possible, please include more details in the question by using the [edit] option below the question.

p1,p2,…pn are not know. They are control inputs calculated and then applied at time points t_1, t_2, ..., t_n.
